# Load sprite (in turtle) without pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to create targets for my 2d shooting game (super basic) but I can't figure out how to load a picture, is this even possible? Right now I use `turtle.stamp()` to make prints but I want a pic instead. I know of `bgpic()` so I'm thinking `turtle.load('image.png')` or something probably exists? Or creating some type of sprite perhaps...

Call me stupid, but I'm trying to do this without using PyGame :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible using Turtle, sadly. However, I vaguely recall a `turtle.begin_poly()` method. This allows you to draw pictures using the turtle and change your turtle to look like them.

```
>>> turtle.home()
>>> turtle.begin_poly()
>>> turtle.fd(100)
>>> turtle.left(20)
>>> turtle.fd(30)
>>> turtle.left(60)
>>> turtle.fd(50)
>>> turtle.end_poly()
>>> p = turtle.get_poly()
>>> register_shape("myFavouriteShape", p)
```

Sadly, this is about the closest you'll get. You can look at [the turtle documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.begin_poly) for more on this, though!

Answer (score 1):

You can only use .gif files in Turtle (can convert any pics and resize free at ezgif.com)

Background:

```
win = turtle.Screen()
win.bgpic('bacground.gif')
```

or whatever the file name is (in same directory).

Using shape gif:

```
win.register_shape('pic1.gif')

target = turtle.Turtle()
target.shape('pic1.gif') # etc
```

Example game:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q49Xyo0LYDs